# c++ order of preference.. how is this expression evaluated?

Tags: c++

I am trying to understand code of some library of one simulation tool that i use..
It has the following line:

```
propData->fadingStretchingFactor =
        (double)(propProfile0->samplingRate) *
        propProfile->dopplerFrequency /
        propProfile0->baseDopplerFrequency /
        (double)SECOND;
```

Now how do u figure out the order of operations if there are two consecutive division operators as in this example

Comment: in the wonderful science of mathematics * and / have no precedence : a/b=a*(1/b) and (a*b)*c=a*(b*c)

Comment: @Hellfrost They most sure do have a precedence: `1+2*3 != (1+2)*3` Many (but not all) programming languages define `*` and `/` with the *same precedence*, and then left-to-right *associativity*.

Comment: @pst - i meant over each other... sometimes English is difficult :-P

Comment: @Hellfrost: This is programming, not math.  For example, `a/b*c` often isn't equal to `a*c/b`.

Comment: it's not eual in math either... i chose my exampels for a reason :-)

Answer (score 6):

Division is left associative.  `a / b / c` is equivalent to `(a / b) / c`.

Note that C (and C++) do not guarantee any ordering between the evaluations of the terms `a`, `b`, and `c`.  For example, `foo() / bar()` could call `foo()` before `bar()` or `foo()` after `bar()`.

Comment: +1 for distinguishing between binding and order of evaluation.

Comment: @ephemient What if both `foo` and `bar` utilize some shared side-effect?

Comment: @pst: Then the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: No, the behavior is unspecified.  Undefined behavior means anything can happen, but that isn't the case here.  Either foo will be called first or bar will be called first, and those calls won't be interwoven.

Answer (score 4):

The grouping of operations of equal precedence is determined by [operator associativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity).

In C++, division is *left-associative*, which means that the leftmost operation is grouped first, i.e.:

```
a / b / c
```

is the same as:

```
(a / b) / c
```

Answer (score 0):

Left to right associativity

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence

Comment: So I suppose in my example we have the following situation: a*b/c/d which due to left to right associativity will be [(a*b)/c]/d which after simplification gives (a*b)/(c*d).. Correct??